# ffmpeg encoding on QuadCore

Tags: cpu, ffmpeg, multi-core

I am trying to push my server's CPU cores to the max, but no success.

Encoding 2-pass style, set my "-threads" to 128 . When running 2nd pass , the CPU seems to be at 98% usage, but first pass run totally ignores "-threads" option.

Using libx264 . Here is my preset:

```
flags=+loop+mv4
cmp=256
partitions=+parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
me_method=hex
subq=7
trellis=1
refs=5
bf=3
flags2=+bpyramid+wpred+mixed_refs+dct8x8
coder=1
me_range=16
g=250
keyint_min=25
sc_threshold=40
i_qfactor=0.71
qmin=10
qmax=51
qdiff=4
```

Is there any reason why the 1st pass is not utilizing my CPUs ?

Thank you in advance! This community has always been very kind to me.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit old this thread is interesting about your problem distributing first pass to multiple cores: http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-141950.html